# How to expose local websocket server to internet using Ngrok and do not get Content-Security-Policy erros in browser?

Tags: nginx, websocket, ngrok

guys!

I am building my own websocket server, which I want to expose to the internet so users could connect to it. Few days ago everything worked perfectly, but now when I am trying to establish connection to my server via browser console I got weird error:
**Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at ws://2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:16620/ (“connect-src”).**

This is what I am doing on my backend:

1. I have python websocket server file with such code:

```
async def handler(websocket, path):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            await websocket.send(json.dumps({'type': 'welcome', 'message': 'Welcome to the server!'}))
            while True:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                data = json.loads(message)
                print(f"Received message from {websocket.remote_address}: {data}")
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            response = {'type': 'error', 'message': str(e)}
            await websocket.send(json.dumps(response))

start_server = websockets.serve(handler, "127.0.0.1",  8080)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

This server runs forever and accepting connections.

2. In terminal I start my ngrok server by command

```
ngrok tcp 8080
```

and it brings me back

```
Forwarding                    tcp://2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:16620 -> localhost:8080
```

And finally in browser in console I put

```
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:16620");
```

and got error

```
Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at ws://2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:16620/ (“connect-src”). 
Uncaught NS_ERROR_CONTENT_BLOCKED:
```

And... I dont know what I am doing wrong. Few days ago (I guess, before I installed Opera on my Linux Mint (I am telling this, because after that I started getting erros with videos in all my browsers, maybe it is a part of a problem)) everything worked perfectly. Now this.

SO why does it happen and what to do, how to fix that?

Tried using wss instead of ws - didnt help. Also different browsers - same result